# How to get linking to work in iphone simulator using phonegap and jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using Phonegap/cordova along with jquery mobile.  When I run the below code in the chrome browser, it works as expected.  However, when I build the application and attempt to run it in the Xcode iPhone simulator, I run into problems.  The first page (parsing json + displaying results) works fine but I'm not able to click on the item and go to the details page.  Any advice on how to fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css">
           <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script> 
           <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

            <style>
                .custom_listview_img {
                    margin:0px; 
                    padding:0px;
                    background-repeat:no-repeat;
                    background-size:100%;
                    height:150px;
                }
                ul {list-style : none; padding:0px;}
            </style>

            <script>
                $(document).on('click','.changePageButton', function() {
                    $.mobile.changePage("#page2");
                });
            </script>

            <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function(){
        var url='http://api.yipit.com/v1/deals/?key=mRSTBQsB49CdMXTW&division=san-francisco&tag=restaurants&lat=37.871087&lon=-122.270913&callback=?';

            $.getJSON(url,function(json){
              $.each(json.response.deals,function(i,item){

                 $("#results").append('<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="a" style="white-space:normal"><a class = "changePageButton" data-transition="slide"><li data-role="list-divider" role="heading" class="ui-li ui-li-divider ui-btn ui-bar-c ui-corner-top">'+item.business.name+'</li><li class="custom_listview_img" style = "background-image:url('+item.images.image_smart+');"></li></a></ul>');

              });
            });   

      });

    </script>
        <title>Hello</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div data-role="page" data-theme="c"> 

            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b"> 
                   <h1>Dealoka</h1> 
            </div> 

             <div data-role="content" id = "results">
                <!-- Display results of parsing json here -->
             </div>   

        </div> 



    <div data-role="page" id="page2" data-add-back-btn="true">
       <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
          <h1>Page 2</h1>
       </div>
       <div data-role="content">
          <p>Deal details</p>
       </div> 
    </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try using the 'vclick' event instead of 'click' in your event handler where the page is changed. vclick seems to perform better for me in this context.

Comment: Great.  Do you want to write an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `vclick` event instead of `click`.

Details here: 
http://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/